# JQuery unbinding a specific handler

Tags: jquery

Given the code below, how can you get `unbind('click', h)` to work?

It doesn't currently work.  I could make `h` a global variable but I don't know how to "set this up" given the `msg` variable is set within the function.

??

```
function x(open) {
    var msg = "blah";

    var h = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showDialog(msg);
    };

    if (open === true) {
        but.unbind('click');
        link.unbind('click');
    } else {
        but.click(h);
        link.click(h);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msg = "blah"

h = function(e) 
{ 
    e.preventDefault();
    showDialog(msg);
};

function x(open) 
{
    msg = "whatever";

    if (open === true) 
    {
        but.unbind('click', h);
        link.unbind('click', h);
    } 
    else 
    {
        but.click(h);       
        link.click(h);      
    }
}
```

*I Think

Comment: Thanks - yes that should work.  It would be nice to do without creating the global `msg` variable (I just prefer to limit the number of global variables).

Comment: What is the reason for a variable message?